# Getting the parameter value on a callback

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a very simple callback class that looks like this

```
class ActivityCallbacks
{
    public class ActivityCallback : Java.Lang.Object, ICallbacks
    {
        Action<JSONObject> onSuccess;
        Action<JSONObject> onFail;

        public ActivityCallback(Action<JSONObject> success, Action<JSONObject> fail = null)
        {
            onFail = fail;
            onSuccess = success;
        }

        public void FailCallback(JSONObject p0)
        {
            onFail?.Invoke(p0);
        }
        public void SuccessCallback(JSONObject p0)
        {
            onSuccess?.Invoke(p0);
        }
    }
}
```

The callback works fine if I use something like

```
someMethod(foo, new ActivityCallbacks.ActivityCallback(success=>...));#
```

This is fine, however there are occasions where I need to be able to use the value the callback is going to receive.

Currently I'm using this (which is incorrect)

```
someClass.SendFile(file, new ActivityCallbacks.ActivityCallback((r) =>
{
      success =>
      {
           try
           {
                 var newmessage = new ChatroomChatMessages(r.GetString("id"), r.GetString("original_file"), Utils.convertTimestampToDate(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis()), "Me :", true, "16", Constants.MyId,  chatroomId);
                 addMessage(newmessage);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
                  //e.printStackTrace();
           }
      },fail => System.Console.WriteLine("failed to send")
 }));
```

By the looks of the error generated, a semicolon is expected at the final success brace. However, this gives me an assignment error.

Am I approaching this the right way to obtain the value of the parameter the callback is expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You need using `success.GetString("id")` in your `try`, because try is inner method of success action, `r` is be passed to `success`, you can only access `sucess` in `try`.

Comment: I thought of that, but changing it still results in the same error - only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: `new ActivityCallbacks.ActivityCallback` accept two parameters of action, why don't you pass `success` and `fail` directly instead of wrap them in `r`.